# How to make front end form only accept certain values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, forms, front-end

I have a front end form, I need that form to attach a taxonomy term to the post, however, I have offered users a dropdown of options, 'a dropdown of custom taxonomy terms.' 
To create this drop down i have tried a select attribute and pulled the terms through as options. 
The problem comes however, due to the fact I have a large multitude of taxonomies that are not practical to show in a dropdown. In this case I pulled the terms through a datalist. 
This then creates the problem that users can, with the code i'm using below, create their own custom taxonomy terms by writing something that isn't suggested by the datalist.

I need to stop this, either by stopping the datalist from allowing values that aren't in the options, or by using

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['terms'], 'products-tax', true);
```

to not accept any taxonomy terms that do not exist, and parse an error to say choose a value value from the list. However, I cannot work out how to do either option.

Any help would be invaluable thank you!

Code I am using:

This is used to set the taxonomy and terms for the post.

```
'tax_input' => array('products-tax' => $_POST['terms'])
```

This attaches the terms

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['terms'], 'products-tax', true);
```

This is the input and datalist that fetches the taxonomy terms and lists them as options.

```
<input type="text" list="products" id="product" name="terms[]" required>
<datalist id="products">
<?php
$products_tax = get_terms('products-tax', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
$counter = 0;
foreach ($products_tax as $product ) {
$counter++;
echo '<option value="'.$product->slug.'">';

}
?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: You can find options by typing with a regular `select` too. Why would you use a `datalist` for that?

Comment: how is it a wordpress specific question?

Comment: Is this about a JavaScript autocomplete?

Comment: @Mark Kaplun it is wordpress specific in that each option is set by the taxonomy term variable, and so I am not sure whether I have to adapt this to stop users from being able to create new terms.

Comment: @toscho That sounds like exactly what I need, however, I cannot figure out how to do this. How do I connect the select field to a text input? I used a datalist because it allows the user to type in and have the taxonomy terms appear, almost like autocomplete, however it does not have fixed values.

Comment: @toscho to my understanding you mean that when you click on the select dropdown and type it takes you to the most relevant value. However, I like datalists, because they provide a proper text box where the user is actually typing, so I guess this becomes a styling issue.

Comment: @NDog, how is filling a datalist a wordpress specific thing? If you can replace the tax with hardcoded values and it still doesn't work as you want, then your problem is with html not wordpress, and if it works then your problem has nothing to do with datalists and you should clarify your question.

Comment: @MarkKaplun ok, apologies, I will ask again in an html forum. And again, I say it is wordpress specific because I am unsure if the `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['terms'], 'products-tax', true);` causes the problem by allowing users to make their own taxonomy term, instead I would want it to parse an error to say 'this product doesn't exist, please choose an eligible product' sort of a thing.

Comment: @MarkKaplun But equally this could also be solved by restricting the values in the form just to the options such as in a select attribute but this doesn't allow users to type anything in. I am just not sure how to do either options!

Comment: @NDog, it is not very clear what is the problem that you are facing, the way I read it you are asking how to properly use datalists. IMO if you think it is wordpress specific then you need to eit the question and explain better what you are trying to do and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I have adapted the question, hopefully it is more relevant, however, I find it difficult to put into words if you can understand. Thanks, and hopefully it is more relevant.

Comment: Have you thinked in validate `$_POST['terms']` against a list of valid valued before you run `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['terms'], 'products-tax', true);`?

Comment: @cybmeta I have considered it but I have a limited knowledge of all these attributes as developing for front end is knew to me ... any chance you could give a little more info in how I would do this? Thanks a lot I would be very grateful.

Comment: Not in frontend, I'm talking about server-side. You can not trust in frontend validation, NEVER, it is useful for user experience and to avoid sending "most" of wrong data. But frontend validation can be altered easily by the user, so **it can be complementary but not replace server-side validation**.

Comment: @cybmeta well, I have a form for logged in users that are logged in using buddypress. So whatever happens, I need a solution to work for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

you will probably want to use `term_exists` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists to check if the term is "valid". Probably worth checking how good is that API with mismatched cases.

Another option is to use AJAX to populated your input control base on the user input. I am almost sure there is some jquery plugin for that, and then hopefully you should be able to use a hidden input to contain the term IDs. This might not be very easy to implement on the server side depending on the details of the values you have to return in each AJAX request.

And what might be the best option if you don't care about that specific page to get a little bloated, is to create an array in javascript that contains all the terms and verify the input against it before sending it to the server (and again send only the term id). You probably have a jquery plugin for this as well, and all that you will need to do on the wordpress side is to generate the javascript array and inject it into the HTML.

Comment: I think the `term_exists` function could possibly work, however, haven't figured out how to implement it.  In terms of the second javascript idea, this could work, however the taxonomy terms will be increasing as new ones will be constantly added and so would be unsustainable to manually add them each time one is made into the javascript array. This could only work if I use a wordpress function to pull them in. However, I am slightly out of my depth. I am very grateful for your input so far though.